# Remove User control from a list contains User Control as well as from a Form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a List contains User Control (`List<myUserControl>`)

and add controls from `List<myUserControl>` to a `TableLayoutPanel`.

Now when user select any `myUserControl` and click on delete button (Located on my Form), I want to `Dispose/remove` that usercontrol from my `Form`.

I able to `Dispose/remove` that usercontrol from my form but don't know how to remove that from a List `List<myUserControl>`

How to match that selected userControl to userControl present in my List

Comment: First you have to make sure that you are not creating a new instance when adding the control to TableLayoutPanel. If they are the same I recomend removing first from the list and then from the TableLayoutPanel,  and the last step will be Dispose. if (list.Contains(myControlInstance)) list.Remove(myControlInstance)

Answer (score 0):

That depends mainly on how you identify selected UserControl. Then after identifying the UserControl you can simply remove it by

```
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(userControl);
myUserControls.Remove(userControl);
```

For Example, I created a UserControl in which i keep a bool to identify it to selected when user clicks it.

```
bool isClicked = false;
    public bool IsClicked
    {
        get
        {
            return isClicked;
        }
        set
        {
            isClicked = value;
            if (value) BackColor = Color.Green;
            else BackColor = Color.Blue;
        }
    }
```

Then on the Form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<MyUserControl> myUserControls = new List<MyUserControl>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) addNewUserControl();
    }

    void addNewUserControl()
    {
        MyUserControl userControl = new MyUserControl();
        userControl.Click += userControl_Click;
        myUserControls.Add(userControl);
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(userControl);
    }

    void userControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < myUserControls.Count; i++) myUserControls[i].IsClicked = false;
        ((MyUserControl)sender).IsClicked = true;
    }

    private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < myUserControls.Count; i++)
            if (myUserControls[i].IsClicked)
            {
                MyUserControl userControl = myUserControls[i];
                tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(userControl);
                myUserControls.RemoveAt(i);
                userControl.Dispose();                
            }

    }
}
```

Here i search for the selected UserControl through a loop and Remove it from the Form and list and dispose it

Comment: From the list I grouping my controls and show group to user which contains 'myUserControl' control.
When user hit delete button, I search group by group to get all the UserControl present in a group and loop to check which User Control is selected in a group and then remove that control, but how to match that usercontrol to usercontrol present in my list and remove that from a list.